# EXPO build failed: Gradle build failed with unknown error

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-build

I am facing the following problem when i try to make a build for a react native expo app. I tried many solution such as delete note module, update expo, different OS etc..

I generate my android folder using yarn eject.

I attached my packages and the error that i get when i execute eas build --platform android

```
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "devtools": "react-devtools"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/config-plugins": "^5.0.2",
    "@expo/prebuild-config": "^5.0.5",
    "@miblanchard/react-native-slider": "^2.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.11",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.7.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.2",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "0.19.0",
    "axios": "^1.2.0",
    "expo": "^47.0.3",
    "expo-app-loading": "~2.1.1",
    "expo-av": "~13.0.3",
    "expo-font": "~11.0.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-secure-store": "~12.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.17.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.8",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.18.0",
    "react-native-shadow-2": "^7.0.8",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-webview": "11.23.1",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "react-devtools": "^4.26.1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@expo/config-plugins": "~7.2.2",
    "@expo/prebuild-config": "~6.2.4"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

```
Specified value for "android.package" in app.json is ignored because an android directory was detected in the project.
EAS Build will use the value found in the native code.
✔ Using remote Android credentials (Expo server)
✔ Using Keystore from configuration: Build Credentials tQR9RzNH8- (default)

Compressing project files and uploading to EAS Build. Learn more
✔ Compressed project files 1s (33.0 MB)
✔ Uploaded to EAS 2s

Build details: https://expo.dev/accounts/obsesie/projects/AwesomeProject/builds/2e44b25d-2f59-42ac-b0f3-59fdd7a6df73

Waiting for build to complete. You can press Ctrl+C to exit.
✖ Build failed

 Android build failed:
Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
```

```
[stderr] 

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

[stderr] 

1: Task failed with an exception.

[stderr] 

-----------

[stderr] 

* What went wrong:

[stderr] 

Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseAarMetadata'.

[stderr] 

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction

[stderr] 

   > 26 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:

[stderr] 

1.  Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1' requires libraries and applications that

[stderr] 

           depend on it to compile against version 32 or later of the

[stderr] 

           Android APIs.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           :app is currently compiled against android-31.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion

[stderr] 

           of at least 32, for example 32.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which

[stderr] 

           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating

[stderr] 

           targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and

[stderr] 

           minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed

[stderr] 

           on).

[stderr] 



[stderr] 

           depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the

[stderr] 

           Android APIs.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           :app is currently compiled against android-31.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle

[stderr] 

           plugin 7.2.1 is 32.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle

[stderr] 

           plugin to one that supports 33, then update this project to use

[stderr] 

           compileSdkVerion of at least 33.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle

[stderr] 

           plugin to one that supports 33, then update this project to use

[stderr] 

           compileSdkVerion of at least 33.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which

[stderr] 

           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating

[stderr] 

           targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and

[stderr] 

           minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed

[stderr] 

           on).

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

       8.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.animation:animation:1.2.1' requires libraries and applications that

[stderr] 

           depend on it to compile against version 32 or later of the

[stderr] 

           Android APIs.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           :app is currently compiled against android-31.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion

[stderr] 

           of at least 32, for example 32.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which

[stderr] 

           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating

[stderr] 

           targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and

[stderr] 

           minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed

[stderr] 

           on).

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

       9.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout:1.3.0-beta02' requires libraries and applications that

[stderr] 

           depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the

[stderr] 

           Android APIs.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           :app is currently compiled against android-31.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle

[stderr] 

           plugin 7.2.1 is 32.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle

[stderr] 

           plugin to one that supports 33, then update this project to use

[stderr] 

           compileSdkVerion of at least 33.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which

[stderr] 

           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating

[stderr] 

           targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and

[stderr] 

           minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed

[stderr] 

           on).

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

      10.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.animation:animation-core:1.2.1' requires libraries and applications that

[stderr] 

           depend on it to compile against version 32 or later of the

[stderr] 

           Android APIs.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           :app is currently compiled against android-31.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion

[stderr] 

           of at least 32, for example 32.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which

[stderr] 

           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating

[stderr] 

           targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and

[stderr] 

           minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed

[stderr] 

           on).

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

      11.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.3.0-beta02' requires libraries and applications that

[stderr] 

           depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the

[stderr] 

           Android APIs.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           :app is currently compiled against android-31.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle

[stderr] 

           plugin 7.2.1 is 32.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle

[stderr] 

           plugin to one that supports 33, then update this project to use

[stderr] 

           compileSdkVerion of at least 33.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which

[stderr] 

           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating

[stderr] 

           targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and

[stderr] 

           minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed

[stderr] 

           on).

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

      12.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-text:1.3.0-beta02' requires libraries and applications that

[stderr] 

           depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the

[stderr] 

           Android APIs.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           :app is currently compiled against android-31.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle

[stderr] 

           plugin 7.2.1 is 32.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle

[stderr] 

           plugin to one that supports 33, then update this project to use

[stderr] 

           compileSdkVerion of at least 33.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which

[stderr] 

           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating

[stderr] 

           targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and

[stderr] 

           minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed

[stderr] 

           on).

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

      13.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-saveable:1.3.0-beta02' requires libraries and applications that

[stderr] 

           depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the

[stderr] 

           Android APIs.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           :app is currently compiled against android-31.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle

[stderr] 

           plugin 7.2.1 is 32.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle

[stderr] 

           plugin to one that supports 33, then update this project to use

[stderr] 

           compileSdkVerion of at least 33.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which

[stderr] 

           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating

[stderr] 

           targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and

[stderr] 

           minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed

[stderr] 

           on).

[stderr] 

14.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics:1.3.0-beta02' requires libraries and applications that

[stderr] 

           depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the

[stderr] 

           Android APIs.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           :app is currently compiled against android-31.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle

[stderr] 

           plugin 7.2.1 is 32.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle

[stderr] 

           plugin to one that supports 33, then update this project to use

[stderr] 

           compileSdkVerion of at least 33.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which

[stderr] 

           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating

[stderr] 

           targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and

[stderr] 

           minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed

[stderr] 

           on).

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

      15.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-unit:1.3.0-beta02' requires libraries and applications that

[stderr] 

           depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the

[stderr] 

           Android APIs.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           :app is currently compiled against android-31.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle

[stderr] 

           plugin 7.2.1 is 32.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle

[stderr] 

           plugin to one that supports 33, then update this project to use

[stderr] 

           compileSdkVerion of at least 33.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which

[stderr] 

           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating

[stderr] 

           targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and

[stderr] 

           minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed

[stderr] 

           on).

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

      16.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-geometry:1.3.0-beta02' requires libraries and applications that

[stderr] 

           depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the

[stderr] 

           Android APIs.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           :app is currently compiled against android-31.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle

[stderr] 

           plugin 7.2.1 is 32.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle

[stderr] 

           plugin to one that supports 33, then update this project to use

[stderr] 

           compileSdkVerion of at least 33.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which

[stderr] 

           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating

[stderr] 

           targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and

[stderr] 

           minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed

[stderr] 

           on).

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

      17.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.3.0-beta02' requires libraries and applications that

[stderr] 

           depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the

[stderr] 

           Android APIs.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           :app is currently compiled against android-31.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle

[stderr] 

           plugin 7.2.1 is 32.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle

[stderr] 

           plugin to one that supports 33, then update this project to use

[stderr] 

           compileSdkVerion of at least 33.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which

[stderr] 

           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating

[stderr] 

           targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and

[stderr] 

           minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed

[stderr] 

           on).

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

      18.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:1.3.0-beta02' requires libraries and applications that

[stderr] 

           depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the

[stderr] 

           Android APIs.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           :app is currently compiled against android-31.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle

[stderr] 

           plugin 7.2.1 is 32.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle

[stderr] 

           plugin to one that supports 33, then update this project to use

[stderr] 

           compileSdkVerion of at least 33.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which

[stderr] 

           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating

[stderr] 

           targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and

[stderr] 

           minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed

[stderr] 

           on).

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

      19.  Dependency 'androidx.emoji2:emoji2-views-helper:1.2.0' requires libraries and applications that

[stderr] 

           depend on it to compile against version 32 or later of the

[stderr] 

           Android APIs.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           :app is currently compiled against android-31.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion

[stderr] 

           of at least 32, for example 32.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which

[stderr] 

           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating

[stderr] 

           targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and

[stderr] 

           minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed

[stderr] 

           on).

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

      20.  Dependency 'androidx.emoji2:emoji2:1.2.0' requires libraries and applications that

[stderr] 

           depend on it to compile against version 32 or later of the

[stderr] 

           Android APIs.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           :app is currently compiled against android-31.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion

[stderr] 

           of at least 32, for example 32.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which

[stderr] 

           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating

[stderr] 

           targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and

[stderr] 

           minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed

[stderr] 

           on).

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

      21.  Dependency 'androidx.customview:customview-poolingcontainer:1.0.0' requires libraries and applications that

[stderr] 

           depend on it to compile against version 32 or later of the

[stderr] 

           Android APIs.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           :app is currently compiled against android-31.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion

[stderr] 

           of at least 32, for example 32.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which

[stderr] 

           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating

[stderr] 

           targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and

[stderr] 

           minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed

[stderr] 

           on).

[stderr] 

22.  Dependency 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0' requires libraries and applications that

[stderr] 

           depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the

[stderr] 

           Android APIs.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           :app is currently compiled against android-31.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle

[stderr] 

           plugin 7.2.1 is 32.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle

[stderr] 

           plugin to one that supports 33, then update this project to use

[stderr] 

           compileSdkVerion of at least 33.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which

[stderr] 

           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating

[stderr] 

           targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and

[stderr] 

           minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed

[stderr] 

           on).

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

      23.  Dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.9.0' requires libraries and applications that

[stderr] 

           depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the

[stderr] 

           Android APIs.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           :app is currently compiled against android-31.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle

[stderr] 

           plugin 7.2.1 is 32.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle

[stderr] 

           plugin to one that supports 33, then update this project to use

[stderr] 

           compileSdkVerion of at least 33.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which

[stderr] 

           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating

[stderr] 

           targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and

[stderr] 

           minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed

[stderr] 

           on).

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

      24.  Dependency 'androidx.profileinstaller:profileinstaller:1.2.0' requires libraries and applications that

[stderr] 

           depend on it to compile against version 32 or later of the

[stderr] 

           Android APIs.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           :app is currently compiled against android-31.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion

[stderr] 

           of at least 32, for example 32.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which

[stderr] 

           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating

[stderr] 

           targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and

[stderr] 

           minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed

[stderr] 

           on).

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

      25.  Dependency 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-util:1.3.0-beta02' requires libraries and applications that

[stderr] 

           depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the

[stderr] 

           Android APIs.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           :app is currently compiled against android-31.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle

[stderr] 

           plugin 7.2.1 is 32.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle

[stderr] 

           plugin to one that supports 33, then update this project to use

[stderr] 

           compileSdkVerion of at least 33.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which

[stderr] 

           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating

[stderr] 

           targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and

[stderr] 

           minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed

[stderr] 

           on).

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

      26.  Dependency 'androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.3.0' requires libraries and applications that

[stderr] 

           depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the

[stderr] 

           Android APIs.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           :app is currently compiled against android-31.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle

[stderr] 

           plugin 7.2.1 is 32.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle

[stderr] 

           plugin to one that supports 33, then update this project to use

[stderr] 

           compileSdkVerion of at least 33.

[stderr] 

     

[stderr] 

           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which

[stderr] 

           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating

[stderr] 

           targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and

[stderr] 

           minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed

[stderr] 

           on).

[stderr] 

* Try:

[stderr] 

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

[stderr] 

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[stderr] 

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

[stderr] 

==============================================================================

[stderr] 

2: Task failed with an exception.

[stderr] 

-----------

[stderr] 

* What went wrong:

[stderr] 

java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

[stderr] 

* Try:

[stderr] 

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

[stderr] 

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[stderr] 

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

[stderr] 

==============================================================================

[stderr] 

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

[stderr] 

BUILD FAILED in 8m 24s

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Execution optimizations have been disabled for 1 invalid unit(s) of work during this build to ensure correctness.

Please consult deprecation warnings for more details.

457 actionable tasks: 457 executed

Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
```

Comment: Can you display the logs of expo.dev builds details? Cause i think you sent only the console logs.

Comment: @Arti partially updated with gradlew

Comment: try a different version of the stripe package, it's always problematic

Comment: @Obsesie did you at anytime of your project execute the command " expo eject " ?

Comment: @Arti, yes i did in order to generate android folder. I needed this to change app version to update it on playstore

Comment: @Obsesie you didn't had to do expo eject do change the app version, you could have done it in app.json using the version prop, but since you did i think you will have to change android/build.gradle file, i will update an awnser with it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to `android/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        androidXCore = "1.6.0" // <-- Add this line
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
```

and make sure that you have :

```
compileSdkVersion = 31
targetSdkVersion = 31
```

If this doens't work you can try :

```
compileSdkVersion = 33
targetSdkVersion = 31
```

for newer react versions.

**PS**: you should avoid using `expo eject`, and do it only when u need to alter native code.

Answer (score 0):

install build properties to update compileSdkVersion by running this command:  `npx expo install expo-build-properties` and in your **app.json** file, add this:

```
"plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "compileSdkVersion": 31,
            "targetSdkVersion": 31,
            "buildToolsVersion": "31.0.0"
          },
          "ios": {
            "deploymentTarget": "13.0"
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
```

Comment: problem persist

Comment: I have the same problem did you find any solution?